# In Python, what's the best way to get an unknown int from a string?

Tags: python, string, parsing, search, built-in

**SOLUTION:** Ok guys I ended up using the following. It involves regular expressions. This is what I was trying to get at.

```
matches = re.findall(r'My favorite chili was number \d+"', line) # gets 1 match
    if matches: # if there are matches
        nums.append(int(re.findall(r'\d+',matches[0])[0])) # append the number
```

This isn't very elegant, but it is extremely robust. It also *always* works based on the format of the files I'm using. Thank you @The2ndSon for suggesting regular expressions. That's what I had vaguely heard of once and couldn't quite remember.

---

### Original Question

In Python, say I am opening a file. In this file there are certain strings that I want. These strings have the format

```
"My favorite chili was chili number NUM"
```

where `NUM` is replaced by a natural number (a non-negative integer).

---

What is the best way to find lines containing this string, and store `NUM`? I have some code laid out, but it seems like there should be a more elegant solution. Are there built-ins made specifically for this purpose? It seems very similar to other string formatting stuff that Python has built-ins for.

---

I am using Python 2.7

---

Here is my code so far:

```
nums = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as txtfile:
    for line in txtfile:
        indx = line.find('My favorite chili was number ')
            if indx != -1:
                nums.append(int(line[indx+30:indx+31]))
```

---

**IMPORTANT EDIT**: There can be more than one number on each line, and the numbers I want are NOT always necessarily at the end. The whole chili thing was just an example.

Comment: Could we see the code you have started?

Comment: If you have working code, you could post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The short answer is regular expressions! Or just `str.startswith` and `str.split`.

Comment: `"My favorite chili was chili number NUM".split(" ")[-1:]`

Comment: Yes, python has "string formatting stuff", but your question is about parsing.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the case. I updated the post.

Comment: `There can be more than one number on each line, and the numbers I want are NOT always necessarily at the end. ` Then what number DO you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to extract digits from a string.

```
>>>import re
>>>re.findall(r'\d+', "My favorite chili was chili number 19")
['19']
```

Comment: And if you have: "My favorite 3 chili was chili number 19" ?

Comment: it would output `['3','19']`, this regular expression should be modified if the intent is to only grab the last element.

Comment: See @KronoS method for grabbing the last element in a string.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't provide enough info. I updated the post. I think I will using regular expressions somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the number is always at the end you can do this:

```
test = "My favorite chili was chili number 123456"

num = int(test.split()[-1])
print(num)
```

Comment: and for lines that don't have a num as the last item - it will raise an exception...

Comment: @alfasin well the OP didn't clarify this.